# Обновление данных после post-запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Посылаем запрос:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/test.php/", data: $(this).serialize(), success: function(html){$("#result").html(html);}});
```

В итоге `#result` заменяется ответом от test.php, который отдаёт массив, и мне нужно на странице обновить не только `#reslut`, но и `#result_1, #result_2, #result_3` из массива отданного test.php. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если массив не ассоциативный, то так, как в коде ниже, в другом случае - обращаться по ключу.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/test.php/", 
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function(html){
        for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                $("#result").html(html[i]);
            } else {
                $("#result_" + i).html(html[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: И еще вопрос небольшой, в test.php у меня отрабатывает функция, которая возращает массив, как данные из этого массива подставить в html[0], html[1]? Массив, не ассоциативный, заполняется данными следующим образом: 
$d[]=val1;
$d[]=val2;
$d[]=val3;

Comment: Толи я вас не понял, толи вы меня. В html - у вас находятся данные переданные из обработчика. Это может быть что угодно, в том числе и массив. Если у вас возвращается массив, то и работайте с ним, как с массивом. К примеру, в test.php вы формируете ответ так:

    $d[]=val1; 
    $d[]=val2; 
    $d[]=val3;
    echo json_encode($d);

В jQuery этот массив уже находится в переменной html. Поэтому html[0] содержит $val1, html[1] - $val2 и , html[2] - $val3

Comment: Распечатанный массив после echo json_encode($d); выглядит как ["111","222","333"]
Но на странице на месте #result появляется [, а должно 111, а на месте #result_2 ], за место 333. Как быть?

Comment: В ajax добавьте еще один параметр: **dataType: 'json'**. Да и вообще, желательно всегда указывать тип ожидаемых данных в ответе.

Comment: Точно, иначе он автоматом всё как строку определяет.
Большое спасибо за помощь. Очень красивое решение с  `$("#result").html(html[i]);`
:-)

Comment: просто ИМХО:

    success: function(html){
        $("#result").html(html[0]);
        for(var i = html.length; i > 0; i--){
             $("#result_" + i).html(html[i]);
        }
    }